# PHP preg_match() doesn't match all subpatterns

Tags: php, regex, match, preg-match

I have a preg_match() which matches the pattern but doesn't receive the expected matches (in third param).

My regex patterns have multiple subpatterns.

```
$pattern = "~^&multi&[^&]+(&(?:(p-(?<sad>[1-9]\d*)|page-(?<sad>[1-9]\d*))))?&[^&]+(&(?:(p-(?<gogosi>[1-9]\d*)|page-(?<gogosi>[1-9]\d*))))?&?$~J";

$string = "&multi&mickael&p-23&george&page-34";

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

This is what $matches contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => &multi&mickael&p-23&george&page-34
    [1] => &p-23
    [2] => p-23
    [sad] => 
    [3] => 23
    [4] => 
    [5] => &page-34
    [6] => page-34
    [gogosi] => 34
    [7] => 
    [8] => 34
)
```

The problem is [sad] should have 23 value.
If I don't include in $string second page (page-34), 'cause is optional [...]

```
$string = "&multi&mickael&p-23&george";
```

[...] I have good $matches 'cause my [sad] got his value:

```
Array
(
    [0] => &multi&mickael&p-23&george
    [1] => &p-23
    [2] => p-23
    [sad] => 23
    [3] => 23
)
```

But I want regex to return properly value even when I have both paginations in $string.

What to do such that all subpatterns will have their value ?

Note: Words as ('p', 'page') are only examples. Can be any words there.

Note: Above data is just an example. Don't give me workaround solutions, but something good for any input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a branch reset group, `(?|...|...)`:

```
'~^&multi&[^&]+(&((?|p-(?<sad>[1-9]\d*)|page-(?<sad>[1-9]\d*))))?&[^&]+(&((?|p-(?<gogosi>[1-9]\d*)|page-(?<gogosi>[1-9]\d*))))?&?$~J'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CCGXql/2).

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/fJnpF):

```
$pattern = "~^&multi&[^&]+(&((?|p-(?<sad>[1-9]\d*)|page-(?<sad>[1-9]\d*))))?&[^&]+(&((?|p-(?<gogosi>[1-9]\d*)|page-(?<gogosi>[1-9]\d*))))?&?$~J";
$string = "&multi&mickael&p-23&george&page-34";
if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => &multi&mickael&p-23&george&page-34
    [1] => &p-23
    [2] => p-23
    [sad] => 23
    [3] => 23
    [4] => &page-34
    [5] => page-34
    [gogosi] => 34
    [6] => 34
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But words as ('p', 'page') are only examples. Can be any words there. Would help me a solution for any subpattern names or input data. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ValentinTanasescu See another answer now.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I also ask you why the fourth parameter PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL doesn't include in $matches unmatched subpatterns with NULL value as should do?

Comment: Why are never included even if that's what documentation says ?

Comment: @ValentinTanasescu Sorry, I might have confused the exact behavior. Looks like it is a new constant and might be buggy.